# Word Mail Merge from two data sources

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I have a bespoke system that produces two data sources (i.e. 2 csv files):  One with basic header info. for clients and another with transactions for the clients.  All in same file with unique client ref no.

Is it possible to set up the mail merge so that Word produces a letter per client with a table in the letter with transaction rows?  The table with transactions will contain data from another data source (csv file) as mentioned above.

Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; this is an end-user issue and therefore off-topic here. It is better asked on a site such as Super User.

Comment: Sorry.  I thought this was an appropriate question as it would require some coding.  I'll post it on Super User instead.  Will be more careful next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the transactions file as an Excel workbook, this is quite possible - provided the file with basic header info contains at least one field found in the transactions file. The solution requires some field coding (programming) to implement:

First, create a Word mailmerge main document and connect it to the file with the basic header info.

Second, create a DATABASE field in the mailmerge main document, coded along the lines of:

```
{DATABASE \d "{FILENAME \p}/../Transactions.xlsx" \s "SELECT [TransDate], [TransID], [TransAmt] FROM [Transactions$] WHERE [ClientID] = {MERGEFIELD ClientID} ORDER BY [InvoiceDate]" \l "9" \b "47" \h}
```

where 'ClientID' is a field found in both the basic header and the transactions file and 'Transactions' in [Transactions$] is the Sheet name.

Once you've done the setup correctly, your merge should be able to produce a letter per client with a table showing the relevant transactions.

A more detailed discussion of this approach can be found at:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2010/mail-merge-to-a-word-table-on-a-single-page/4edb4654-27e0-47d2-bd5f-8642e46fa103. For a working example, see:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/37844-mail-merge-using-one-excel-file-multiple.html

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.

For more info on the DATABASE field, see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-database-field-04398159-a2c9-463f-bb59-558a87badcbc?ocmsassetID=HP010260104&CorrelationId=13f3ddc8-95e9-4b61-a577-61e3f961c75d&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try this solution and see how it works out.